# take information from an array and load it to a table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, datatables

thanks for reading my post!

I've been trying to create a function that will take the objects in an array of employee data and display them in a table.

Within the class called 'system', I have system.giveAllEmployees(), which returns the array of all the employees, while system.giveAllOffers() returns all the active offers that have been put in the system. It should all be organized in the table employeeData, and run through and see how many offers each employee is assigned to, and add that to the table as well. It works and loads to the table but instead of updating the offer for each employee, whenever a new offer is loaded to the system it updates the offer number for all the employees in the table.

I assume this is because of how i set up the loop? but i'm really stumped as to why this is happening. I can provide any other information or code needed, if anyone knows a better way to load data from arrays into a table id appreciate that as well!

```js
function loadAll() {
  var a      = system.giveAllEmployees();
  var b      = system.giveAllOffers();
  var tr     = "";
  var table  = document.getElementById("employeeData");
  let offers = 0;
  
  table.innerHTML = "";

  a.forEach( x => {   
    b.forEach( y => {
      if (x.employeeName === y.name) {
        offers += 1;
      }
      return offers;
    }),
    tr += '<tr>';
    tr += '<td>' + x.name + '</td>' 
        + '<td>' + x.document + '</td>' 
        + '<td>' + x.departament + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + x.age + '</td>' 
        + '<td>' + offers + '</td>';
    tr += '</tr>';
    offers = 0;
  })
  table.innerHTML += tr;
}
```

And for context, here's a picture of the table the data is loaded into:

[image: Table]

Thanks again for any tips or help on this issue!

Comment: `forEach` does nothing with the `return`. The loop logic is wrong. If you provide an example data, a [mre], we can help.

Comment: @0stone0 Hello! What do you mean by example data? An example array of employee data?

Comment: Please provide full HTML and JS, and please provide example of the employee and offer data.

Comment: Hi @Mina, how would I provide the full HTML and JS code? In two code blocks?

Comment: not giving here a significant sample of your data, makes your problem even more difficult to apprehend

Comment: @itsacode001 you can find an icon <> called "code snippet", if you click on it, it will open a code editor for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect a careless error:

**change**
`if (x.employeeName === y.name) {`
**to**
`if (y.employeeName === x.name) {`

full code:
for info -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow

```
function loadAll()
  {
  const
    Employees = system.giveAllEmployees()
  , Offers    = system.giveAllOffers()
  , tableBody = document.querySelector('#employee-table > tbody')
    ;
  tableBody.innerHTML = '';

  Employees.forEach( emp => 
    {
    let newRow = tableBody.insertRow()

    newRow.insertCell().textContent = emp.name
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = emp.document
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = emp.departament
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = emp.age
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = Offers.filter(({employeeName:eNam})=>eNam===emp.name).length
    })
  }
```

**Demo** (*and to show you how to do for your next questions*)

```js
function loadAll()
  {
  const
    Employees = system.giveAllEmployees()
  , Offers    = system.giveAllOffers()
  , tableBody = document.querySelector('#employee-table > tbody')
    ;
    tableBody.innerHTML = '';

  Employees.forEach( emp => 
    {
    let newRow = tableBody.insertRow()

    newRow.insertCell().textContent = emp.name
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = emp.document
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = emp.departament
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = emp.age
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = Offers.filter(({employeeName: eNam})=>eNam===emp.name).length
    })
  }


// test datas
const system = 
  {
    giveAllEmployees() {
      return (
        [ { name: 'Joseph', document: '123456', departament : 'Artgas', age: 23 }
        , { name: 'Mary',   document: '666222', departament : 'Artgas', age: 41 }
      ] ) }
  , giveAllOffers() {
      return (
        [ { employeeName: 'Mary',   xxx: 'xxx' }
        , { employeeName: 'Joseph', zzz: 'zzz' }
        , { employeeName: 'Mary',   yyy: 'yyy' }
      ] ) }
  };

//  testing :
loadAll()
```

```css
table#employee-table {
  font-family      : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size        : 12px;
  border-collapse  : separate;
  border-spacing   : 1px;
  background-color : darkslategrey;
  } 
#employee-table th,
#employee-table td {
  background-color : whitesmoke;
  padding          : .3em .6em;
  text-align       : center;
  }
```

```html
<table id="employee-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Employee Name</th> <th>Document</th> <th>Departement</th> <th>Age</th> <th>Number of Offers</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Holy crap this actually worked like a charm! Thank you so much for including the demo as well, really helped me figure out what parts I was missing. You're the best!

Comment: @itsacode001 I know it well !, but don't say it too much around you, it makes people jealous; and then I'm sure that one of these days you'll pass me, it's in the order of things...